# dplyr dynamically generate column to mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe which has a column for a date, another column for an amount, and various columns that contain years. I want to put the values from the amount column into the year column that corresponds to year in the date column. For example,

```
ID    Date         Amount        2010    2011    2012
01    2010/05/05   200           200
02    2011/05/05   300                   300
03    2012/05/05   400                           400
```

Is there a way I can dynamically choose which column to mutate based on the value of the date column?

Comment: I'm interested as to why this "untidy" format is necessary? As opposed to, for example, just creating a single `Year` column, or just converting date to year as required?

Comment: The original data was processed that way, so I was trying to replicate that format for compatibility. In the end, I decided against it though, it got quite messy.

Answer (score 4):

After transforming the date to a year using `lubridate`'s `year`, you can use `spread` from the `tidyr` package to spread your data out:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df = read.table(text = "ID    Date         Amount
            01    2010/05/05   200        
            02    2011/05/05   300     
            03    2012/05/05   400 ", header= TRUE)

df %>% 
    mutate(y = lubridate::year(Date)) %>% 
    spread(key = y, value = Amount)
```

The missing data points will be `NA`'s.  If you prefer blank strings like in your sample, instead try:

```
... %>%
    spread(key = y, value = Amount, fill = "")
```

Note that the resulting dataframe no longer has an `Amount` column, but you can get it back by merging to the original data.

Comment: you can keep the Amount column by setting `drop` parameter to `FALSE`, no need to remerge :)

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, there is also a "one-liner" using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(DF, ID + Date + Amount ~ year(Date), fill = "")
```

Note that the `year` columns are computed *on-the-fly*. So there is no need to create a helper `y` variable before reshaping.

> ```
>   ID       Date Amount 2010 2011 2012
> 1 01 2010-05-05    200  200          
> 2 02 2011-05-05    300       300     
> 3 03 2012-05-05    400            400
> ```

#### Data

```
DF <- structure(list(ID = c("01", "02", "03"), Date = structure(c(14734, 
15099, 15465), class = "Date"), Amount = c(200L, 300L, 400L)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Date", "Amount"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```